# firefoxのURLバーをクリック (フォーカス) すると拡大するのを無効にしたい

Tags: firefox

新しいFirefoxだとURLバーをクリックするとURLバーが広がってしまいます。
オプションと `about:config` を検索しましたがそれでもURLバーの拡大を無効にする仕方は書かれていませんでした。
どうやってこれを拡大しないようにできますか？

あとこういうのの設定をどこでいじるかはどうやって調べればいいですか？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firefox 77 では `browser.urlbar.update1` オプションによる**当該機能のオプトアウトが行えません**<sup>[[1]](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1627969)</sup>。よって、別の方法を用いる必要があります。ここでは [Firefox Support Forum の投稿](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/firefox?tagged=megabar&show=all)を参考に、 userChrome.css を使用する方法を紹介します。

もし userChrome.css を使用したことがない場合は、事前に以下の手順を実行してください。

1. `about:config` にて `toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` を `true` に設定する
2. `about:support` で表「アプリケーション基本情報」にある項目「プロファイルフォルダー」の「フォルダーを開く」ボタンをクリックする
3. 開いたディレクトリに `chrome` というディレクトリを作成する
4. `chrome` ディレクトリに `userChrome.css` ファイルを作成する

---

以上の手順を完了したら、次に [Megabar – Configuring and Styling the Firefox 75 Address Bar](https://www.userchrome.org/megabar-styling-firefox-address-bar.html) というサイトで、アドレスバーの拡大に関する userChrome.css 用の装飾を取得します。今回検証のために取得した装飾は、以下のようになっています。最後に、この装飾を先ほどの手順で作成した `userChrome.css` ファイルにコピーし、ファイルを保存した後に Firefox を再起動することで、作業は完了です。

```css
/*** Megabar Styler General - version 2020-04-19 ***/



  /*** General Preferences ***/

  :root {

    /* Number of pixels of enlargement when URL bar is focused */

    --mbarstyler-popout-pixels: 0px; /* [0px - 7px] */



    /* Top Bar Display or Not */

    --mbarstyler-top-bar-display: block; /* [block,none] */



    /* Font sizes (default: 13.8px for title, 10.2px for URL) */

    --mbarstyler-title-font-size: 15px; /* [13px - 18px] */

    --mbarstyler-url-font-size: 13px; /* [12px - 16px] */



    /* Rows to show without scrolling */

    --mbarstyler-max-rows-without-scrolling: 10;



    /* Bottom border for each result row */

    --mbarstyler-bottom-border-width: 0px; /* [0px or 1px] */

    

    /* Match display style */

    --mbarstyler-match-weight: 700; /* [400,700] */

    --mbarstyler-match-background-opacity: 0.0; /* [0.0,0.05,0.1] */

  }



  /*** URL bar enlargement or lack thereof ***/



  /* Compute new position, width, and padding */

  #urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend] {

    top: calc(5px - var(--mbarstyler-popout-pixels)) !important;

    left: calc(0px - var(--mbarstyler-popout-pixels)) !important;

    width: calc(100% + (2 * var(--mbarstyler-popout-pixels))) !important;

    padding: var(--mbarstyler-popout-pixels) !important;

  }

  [uidensity="compact"] #urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend] {

    top: calc(3px - var(--mbarstyler-popout-pixels)) !important;

  }

  [uidensity="touch"] #urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend] {

    top: calc(4px - var(--mbarstyler-popout-pixels)) !important;

  }



  /* Prevent shift of URL bar contents */

  #urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend] > #urlbar-input-container {

    height: var(--urlbar-height) !important;

    padding: 0 !important;

  }



  /* Do not animate */

  #urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend] > #urlbar-background {

    animation: none !important;;

  }



  /* Remove shadows */

  #urlbar[breakout][breakout-extend] > #urlbar-background {

    box-shadow: none !important;

  }



  /*** Top "Blue Bar" Display ***/



  .urlbarView-row:first-of-type {

    display: var(--mbarstyler-top-bar-display) !important;

  }



  /*** Font Sizes and Scrolling ***/



  /* Title font-size */

  .urlbarView-row .urlbarView-title {

    font-size: var(--mbarstyler-title-font-size) !important;

  }



  /* URL / action font-size */

  .urlbarView-row .urlbarView-secondary,

  .urlbarView-row .urlbarView-url,

  .urlbarView-row .urlbarView-action {

    font-size: var(--mbarstyler-url-font-size) !important;

  }



  /* Set max-height for items visible without scrolling */

  #urlbarView-results, #urlbar-results {

    height: unset !important;

    max-height: calc(2.5 * (var(--mbarstyler-title-font-size) + var(--mbarstyler-bottom-border-width)) * var(--mbarstyler-max-rows-without-scrolling)) !important;

  }

  #urlbar-results {

    overflow-y: auto !important; 

  }



  /* Clean up extra spacing at the top and bottom */  

  #urlbar-results {

    padding-top: 0 !important;

    padding-bottom: 0 !important;

  }



  /* Subtle border between results */

  .urlbarView-row:not(:last-of-type) {

    border-bottom: var(--mbarstyler-bottom-border-width) solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) !important;

  }



  /* Match Styling Like Fx43-47 */

  [lwt-popup-darktext] .urlbarView-row:not([selected]) .urlbarView-title strong,

  [lwt-popup-darktext] .urlbarView-row:not([selected]) .urlbarView-url strong {

    font-weight: var(--mbarstyler-match-weight) !important;

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, calc(var(--mbarstyler-match-background-opacity) * 2));

    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, var(--mbarstyler-match-background-opacity));

    border-radius: 2px;

  }

  [lwt-popup-brighttext] .urlbarView-row:not([selected]) .urlbarView-title strong,

  [lwt-popup-brighttext] .urlbarView-row:not([selected]) .urlbarView-url strong {

    font-weight: var(--mbarstyler-match-weight) !important;

    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, calc(var(--mbarstyler-match-background-opacity) * 2));

    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, var(--mbarstyler-match-background-opacity));

    border-radius: 2px;

  }



/*** End of: Megabar Styler General ***/



/*** Megabar Styler Two-Row Flex Layout - version 2020-04-12 ***/



  /* !!! Requires variables from Megabar Styler General !!! */



  /* Adjust heights for scrolling */

  #urlbarView-results, #urlbar-results {

    max-height: calc(1.625 * (var(--mbarstyler-title-font-size) + var(--mbarstyler-url-font-size) + var(--mbarstyler-bottom-border-width)) * var(--mbarstyler-max-rows-without-scrolling)) !important;

  }

    /* Wrap the url (adapted from Fx75 narrow bar design) */

  .urlbarView-row-inner {

    flex-wrap: wrap !important;

    padding-top: 0 !important;

    padding-bottom: 2px !important;

  }

  .urlbarView-no-wrap {

    max-width: 100% !important;

    flex-basis: 100% !important;

    position: relative;

  }



  /* Adjust horizontal and vertical URL position */

  .urlbarView-row[has-url] > .urlbarView-row-inner > .urlbarView-url {

    padding-inline-start: calc(6px + 2px + /* favicon */ 16px) !important;

    margin-top: calc(2px + (var(--mbarstyler-url-font-size) - var(--mbarstyler-title-font-size)));

  }



  /* Hide the separator if there's a URL */

  .urlbarView.megabar[actionoverride] .urlbarView-row[has-url] .urlbarView-title-separator,

  .urlbarView.megabar .urlbarView-row[has-url]:not([type$=tab]) .urlbarView-title-separator,

  .urlbarView.megabar .urlbarView-row[type=remotetab]:-moz-any(:hover, [selected]) .urlbarView-title-separator {

    display: none !important;

  }



  /* Move Switch Tab info to URL line :: added 2020-04-12 */



    /* Make sure URL is always visible */

    .urlbarView-row[type="switchtab"][has-url="true"] .urlbarView-url {

      visibility: visible !important;

    }

    /* Show Switch to Tab or Open depending on [actionoverride] */

    .urlbarView:not([actionoverride]) .urlbarView-row[type="switchtab"][has-url="true"] .urlbarView-url::before {

      content: "Switch to Tab: ";

      font-style: italic;

      color: var(--urlbar-popup-action-color);

    }

    .urlbarView[actionoverride] .urlbarView-row[type="switchtab"][has-url="true"] .urlbarView-url::before {

      content: "Open: ";

      font-style: italic;

      color: var(--urlbar-popup-action-color);

    }

    /* Hide the existing Action phrase and separator */

    .urlbarView-row[type="switchtab"][has-url="true"] .urlbarView-action,

    .urlbarView-row[type="switchtab"][has-url="true"] .urlbarView-title-separator {

      display: none !important;

    }



/*** End of: Megabar Styler Two-Row Flex Layout ***/
```

再起動後にアドレスバーへフォーカスすると、アドレスバーの拡大がされていないことがわかります。以下に私の環境での動作例を示します。

**フォーカス前**
[image: フォーカスをする前のアドレスバーはuserChrome.cssを適用する前と同じ外観に見える]

**フォーカス後**
[image: フォーカスをするとアドレスバーは拡大せず、アドレスバーの周囲の灰色の線が青色の線に変化する]

---

参考:

- [1627969 - Remove browser.urlbar.update1 pref](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1627969)
- [Firefox Support Forum | Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/firefox?tagged=megabar&show=all)
- [Megabar – Configuring and Styling the Firefox 75 Address Bar](https://www.userchrome.org/megabar-styling-firefox-address-bar.html)

Answer (score 3):

Redditで同様の話題がありました。
https://www.reddit.com/r/FirefoxCSS/comments/de6xc7/disable_expanding_addressbar/

`about:config`で`browser.urlbar.update1` を `false`にすればオフにできます。

調べ方ですが今回はGoogle検索で"firefox expand address bar disable"で出てきました。

他にもFirefoxであれば専用のフォーラムで質問するなどの方法が考えられます。
https://forums.mozillazine.jp/